# Multiple divs, how to select the a div with an a tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried many different things, but I could not solve my problem.

I have two exactly same `div`s. In the `div`s, there are `<A>` tags. When I click one of them, the two `<div>` tags are changing simultaneouly. How can I change only the clicked one?

Piece of my code :

```
$.fn.infiniteCarousel = function () {
     $('a.rsBulletFirst',this).click(function() {
         alert("fds");
         $("#bulThird").removeClass("rsNavSelected");
         $("#bulSecond").removeClass("rsNavSelected");
         $("#bulFirst").addClass("rsNavSelected");
         return gotoPage(1);
     });
     $('a.rsBulletSecond',this).click(function() {
         $("#bulThird").removeClass("rsNavSelected");
         $("#bulSecond").addClass("rsNavSelected");
         $("#bulFirst").removeClass("rsNavSelected");
         return gotoPage(2);
     });
     $('a.rsBulletThird',this).click(function() {
         $("#bulThird").addClass("rsNavSelected");
         $("#bulSecond").removeClass("rsNavSelected");
         $("#bulFirst").removeClass("rsNavSelected");
         return gotoPage(3);
     });
}
```

My code in JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fjdgjse1/

Comment: in your click function you look for all ids, use $(this).closest("#bulThird") maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The selectors return an array of items matching your selection so you have to get the first element like this:

```
 $("#bulThird").get(0)
```

Comment: You are selecting by id, there shouldn't be more than 1.